# How to do a complex search in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, rscript

I have a data frame that has the 14 columns. 2 of those 14 columns are "Region" and "Population Density." Lets say that I want to find all instances when region is 4 and print out what the value of the population density is for each instance of region = 4.

here I am going to add a new column in the data frame called "PopDens"
this new column will take the total population and divided it by
the land region

```
    cdi.df$PopDens= cdi.df$TotalPop/cdi.df$LandArea
    dim(cdi.df) #here I verify the columns are now 14 and not 13
    head(cdi.df) #here I verify that the name and calculations are correct
    head(cdi.df$PopDens, 3) #here I return only the first three values
```

Is there a way to return only values of pop dens when region is =4?

Comment: Do you want all of the columns for which region is 4? Or do you just want a vector of the population densities for which region is 4?  Either way this is in no way a "complex" search.

Answer (score 3):

Just like this:

```
cdi.df[cdi.df$Region==4,] #to see the data.frame with only region 4
cdi.df$PopDens[cdi.df$Region==4] #to see only the population densities
```

Next time, please provide a reproducible eaxmple, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).